# How to vizualize each instances of dataframe with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time series data in the format for 24 hours which after conversion from epoch is as:

```
  time                     d
 0  2018-06-30 18:30:45  41000000000  
 1  2018-06-30 18:31:44  40000000000  
 2  2018-06-30 18:32:44  41000000000  
 3  2018-06-30 18:33:45  41000000000  
 4  2018-06-30 18:34:45  41000000000  
 5  2018-06-30 18:35:45  41000000000  
 6  2018-06-30 18:36:47  44000000000  
 7  2018-06-30 18:37:46  43000000000  
 8  2018-06-30 18:38:46  40000000000  
 9  2018-06-30 18:39:47  43000000000
10  2018-06-30 18:45:47  41000000000
11  2018-06-30 18:46:47  40000000000
12  2018-06-30 18:47:47  40000000000
13  2018-06-30 18:48:45  38000000000
14  2018-06-30 18:49:48  40000000000
15  2018-06-30 18:50:48  41000000000
16  2018-06-30 18:51:48  41000000000
17  2018-06-30 18:52:47  40000000000
18  2018-06-30 18:53:47  40000000000
19  2018-06-30 18:54:47  41000000000
20  2018-06-30 18:55:47  41000000000
21  2018-06-30 18:56:47  40000000000
22  2018-06-30 18:57:47  41000000000
23  2018-06-30 18:58:50  44000000000
24  2018-06-30 18:59:49  43000000000
25  2018-06-30 19:00:48  39000000000
26  2018-06-30 19:01:48  39000000000
27  2018-06-30 19:02:48  39000000000
28  2018-06-30 19:03:48  39000000000
29  2018-06-30 19:04:48  39000000000
..                  ...          ...
136 2018-06-30 20:52:04  43000000000
137 2018-06-30 20:53:04  43000000000
138 2018-06-30 20:54:04  43000000000
139 2018-06-30 20:55:01  40000000000
140 2018-06-30 20:56:04  43000000000
141 2018-06-30 20:57:04  39000000000
142 2018-06-30 20:58:04  40000000000
143 2018-06-30 20:59:04  40000000000
144 2018-06-30 21:00:04  40000000000
145 2018-06-30 21:01:04  41000000000
146 2018-06-30 21:02:04  40000000000
147 2018-06-30 21:03:05  41000000000
148 2018-06-30 21:04:05  41000000000
149 2018-06-30 21:05:05  41000000000
150 2018-06-30 21:06:05  41000000000
151 2018-06-30 21:07:05  41000000000
152 2018-06-30 21:08:05  41000000000
153 2018-06-30 21:09:05  41000000000
154 2018-06-30 21:10:05  41000000000
155 2018-06-30 21:11:04  40000000000
156 2018-06-30 21:12:04  39000000000
157 2018-06-30 21:13:04  39000000000
158 2018-06-30 21:14:03  39000000000
159 2018-06-30 21:15:06  42000000000
160 2018-07-01 18:30:48  39000000000
161 2018-07-01 18:31:48  39000000000
162 2018-07-01 18:32:48  40000000000
163 2018-07-01 18:33:49  41000000000
164 2018-07-01 18:34:48  40000000000
165 2018-07-01 18:35:48  40000000000
```

Like this I am having 165 rows.

To plot it as in scatter form I used following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates

df = pd.read_csv('Mlogi_ALL_sy_5.csv')

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

df.plot(x = 'time' , y = 'd', style = "." )
```

But above gives me only a specific interval plot. The data is from `2018-06-30 18:30:45` to `2018-07-01 18:35:48` i.e 24 hours but I get plot   for `2018-06-30 18:30:45` to `2018-06-30 21:21:45` while plotting through matplotlib in pandas dataframe.

For reference I am attaching the plot screen shot.

[image: Improper plot]

How can I have a scatter plot for full 24 hours of data i.e all 165 rows properly??

Comment: If you have 60 rows for each hour, it seems correct that in 3h there are about 165-180 rows(from 18:30 till 21:21)

Comment: @Joe Actually data is from `2018-06-30 18:30:45` to `2018-07-01 18:30:45` i.e 24 hours but I get plot is for `2018-06-30 18:30:45` to `2018-06-30 21:21:45`

Comment: @jpp Kindly have a look on my problem ... :)

Comment: But the first 10 rows are just for 10 minutes, arent they? is a row for each minute for the rest of df? because if it is so, you would have 1500 rows, not 165

Comment: @Joe I have updated the full data in main section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the data you provided and faking the missing ones i execute your code, and this is the output:

[image]

Is this what you expected?
The code:

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')
df.plot(x = 'time' , y = 'duration', style = "." )
```

Is `d` in your code the name `duration` in your df?

Comment: `d` is the column that depicts `duration`. My actual concern is I am getting plot only upto `2018-06-30 21:21:45` but there is data for `2018-07-01` too which is not there in plot .... @Joe I am searching solution for this ...can this be solved by `xticklabels` ??

Comment: `plt.xlim(None, df.index[-1])`
`Out[21]: (0.0, 165)`

And it includes a blank `graph`

Comment: Try with: `plt.xlim(df['time'].iloc[0], df['time'].iloc[-1])`

Comment: YES `plt.xlim(df['time'].iloc[0], df['time'].iloc[-1])` works ...show some `.` on `2018-07-01` date now ...but how the labels here can come exactly as `time` column ? @Joe

Comment: You mean how is that possible?

Comment: I need labels as in x axis as mentioned in columns `time` as  `2018-06-30 18:30:45` How that can be made ?